# Django: Fullcalendar : year view

Tags: jquery, django, plugins, fullcalendar

I tried for a while to adjust viewing on one year of events with "fullcalendar-1.6.4-release yearview"
the demo works but not my code

in the demo, there is this :

```
<head>
<link href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='../lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
.....
```

in my code, I put the full path

```
<link href='D:/PYTHON_DJANGO/projet2/notes/templates/notes/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='D:/PYTHON_DJANGO/projet2/notes/templates/notes/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='D:/PYTHON_DJANGO/projet2/notes/templates/notes/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='D:/PYTHON_DJANGO/projet2/notes/templates/notes/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src='D:/PYTHON_DJANGO/projet2/notes/templates/notes/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

but its not working
what is the problem ?

my code works with :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{% static 'fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' %}' />

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
```

if I replace by :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

its not works..

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Also, learn about Django static file configuration.

Comment: I tried also with static files, but I display nothing. My program works and display month, week, day. The problem is jquery.min.js. if I replace with jquery-1.7.1.min.js, it works (I dont display the year)

Comment: It works ! I display year, month, week, day. the problem was fullcalendar.min.js. You have tu use exactly the same files that the package "fullcalendar-1.6.4-yearview"